# Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) : Http Client Processor app's retry mechanism causing issues during retry

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Im using Http Client Processor app in one of my stream which is a standard app of SCDF.The puspose of this app is to make http calls against provided URL with a message payload. I tried to enable the retry mechanism of this app by keeping the boolean httpclient.retry.enabled to 'true'.

But when I do that it try to repost the message against the http end point even if the first attempt is succecssfull. It looks like it is working with the concept of 'write at least once'. The problem with this approach is, it creates duplicates in the target system.

Is there a way we can configure it for 'write just once if the call is successful else, retry'. If not can we expect a fix from Spring ?

Answer (score 1):

The Http Client Processor is no longer supported. I recommend upgrading to [HttpRequestProcessor](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/tree/main/applications/processor/http-request-processor). This uses the common retry mechanism included in the messaging binder. The behavior is as you describe, the request will be retried only if the consumer fails to acknowledge the message. With at least once guarantees, you still have the potential for duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this.